# Como fazer update em uma coleção no laravel/eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, upload

Estou usando o repository do laravel em meu projeto. Criei um Service pra adicionar algumas regras. No método de upload é um método reutilizável tanto para salvar como para atualizar imagem. 
O método salvar funciona perfeitamente com o método de upload.
O método update faz o processo de upload mas não salva os dados no banco.
Qnd eu recebo os dados da imagem no método de upload eles chegam da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dps que eles fz o upload e retorna os dados com o nome do arquivo renomeado retorna assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Método de salvar:

```
public function save($files, $id)
{
    $arr = $this->doUpload($files);
    foreach($arr as $entry)
    {
      $entry->projects_id = $id->id;
      $entry->save();
    }
    return;
}
```

Método de update que não acontece nada:

```
 public function updateImage($files, $id)
{
     $arr = $this->doUpload($files);
     foreach ($arr as $key) {
      $key = array(
        'filename' => $key->filename,
        'original_filename'=> $key->original_filename,
        'mime'=> $key->mime,
         );
     }
    return $this->uploadsRepository->update($arr, $id);

}
```

E tentei assim também:

```
 public function updateImage($files, $id)
{
     $arr = $this->doUpload($files);

     foreach ($arr as $key) {
      $this->uploadsRepository->update($key, $id);
     }
    return ;

}
```

Que retorna o erro:

**Argument 1 passed to Prettus\Repository\Eloquent\BaseRepository::update() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\projetos\painel\app\Services\ProjectService.php on line 45 and defined**

Answer (score 1):

Eu consegui fazer assim:

```
Uploads::where('id', $id)->update($key);
```

Mas n achei uma boa prática.. sei lá..

O que vcs acham?

esse Uploads:: ?